# error C2018: unknown character 0x13 (which is DC3 in ascii)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

While compiling some C++ code in VS2013 I got this error and this is the first time I have seen it also.
When I click the error message it refers to a specific line in `sal.h` header, which is:

```
    // buffer capacity is described by a complex expression
#define _Out_z_cap_x_(size)               _SAL1_1_Source_(_Out_*Ÿö Ÿ(ôÜ_Øize), _Pre_cap_x_(size)         _Post_valid_impl_ _Post_z_)
```

I wonder how to resolve this issue?

Comment: That header file appears to be corrupted. The equivalent line in my VS2012 installation is `#define _Out_z_cap_x_(size)               _SAL1_1_Source_(_Out_z_cap_x_, (size), _Pre_cap_x_(size)         _Post_valid_impl_ _Post_z_)`. Reinstalling or repairing Visual Studio may fix the issue.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion, thank you sir

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Repairing VS solved my problem.